# The specified child already has a parent.In table layout

Tags: android, runtime-error, parent-child, android-tablelayout

i want to set 1 image per 1 column but error is The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first. Can you get a easy explain to me . how can i do?

this is my code

```
 public class MybookActivity extends Activity{

private BooksDB db;
private Context context;
private HashMap< String, ArrayList<String>> hm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_mybook_sub2);

    ArrayList<String> list_bokID = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list_title = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> list_theme = new ArrayList<String>();
    hm = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();


    context = this;
    db = new BooksDB(context);
    hm = db.getBookTheme();
    if(hm.isEmpty() == true){
        System.out.println("NO data");

    }else{
        System.out.println("have data");
        list_bokID = hm.get("bokID");
        for (String bokID : list_bokID){
            System.out.println(bokID);
        }
        list_title = hm.get("title");
        for (String title : list_title) {
            System.out.println(title);

        }
        list_theme = hm.get("theme");
        for (String themePath : list_theme) {
            System.out.println(themePath);
        }
    }

    int Theme_size = list_theme.size();
    //new
    int numRow = Theme_size / 2;
    int numCol = 5;

    TableLayout tblLayout = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblLayout);

    for(int i = 0; i < numRow; i++) {
        HorizontalScrollView HSV = new HorizontalScrollView(this);
        HSV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));

        TableRow tblRow = new TableRow(this);
        tblRow.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tblRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.newshell);

        for(int j = 0; j < numCol; j++) {
            ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

            for (String string : list_theme) {
                int res_id = getResources().getIdentifier(string, "drawable", getPackageName());
                imageView.setImageResource(res_id);
                tblRow.addView(imageView,j);
            }
        }

        HSV.addView(tblRow);
        tblLayout.addView(HSV, i);
    }
}




}
```

thank you

Comment: show this xml code too layout_mybook_sub2

Answer (score 0):

You need a new instance of each image view that is added (and any view added to a ViewGroup).

Move the instance creation inside the for inner loop:

```
for (String string : list_theme) {
   ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

   int res_id = getResources().getIdentifier(string, "drawable", getPackageName());
   imageView.setImageResource(res_id);
   tblRow.addView(imageView,j);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Eskimo. but i want to set 1 imageview per 1 column.But now 1 imageview per every column . Why be that.

Comment: I can't understand you.